# Disk space of a device on the same network

Tags: php, path, protocols, diskspace

So the core thing what I'm trying to do is get the disk space from a other Device that is on the same network.

I use the PHP function [disk_total_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php) for this. I'm using the connecting string `\\192.168.0.1\c$`.

So in total I would have:

```
disk_total_space('\\\\192.168.0.1\\c$');
```

However, I have some questions about this connection string, to begin with:

1. With what protocol does this 'URL' connect?
2. why does it need a $ at the end of the driver?

Now I also need to give username and password with my connection string. However I don't know how to fuse this with the connection string I have.
I tried to give the username and password with an FTP-protocol and an HTTPS-protocol, but none seems to work.

```
https:\\\\username:password@\\\\192.168.0.1\\c$
ftp:\\\\username:password@\\\\192.168.0.1\\c$
```

As you might notice I'm new to these protocols, so I hope anyone could explain this to me.

Comment: This will not work, see the php documentation you linked yourself: Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about php, but it seems like to answer this question you need no php knowledge... Hope this helps:

*1. With what protocol does this 'url' connect?*

This is called [UNC Path](http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html).  See more details from [wiki: Path (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC_in_Windows)

Quote:

`A UNC path describes the location of a volume, directory, or file.
The format for a UNC path is \\server\volume\directory\file and is not case-sensitive.`

*2. Why does it need a $ at the end of the driver?*

The `$` stands for a hidden share, see more from [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984)

*3. For your last question, 'Passing UNC username and password within a UNC path'*

There is an answer to a similar question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/344775/passing-unc-username-and-password-within-a-unc-path).

***Quote answer from [@grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/344775/passing-unc-username-and-password-within-a-unc-path#answer-344933)***

On Windows, you *cannot* put credentials in UNC paths. You must provide them using `net use`, `runas /netonly`, or when asked by Windows. (If you have some programming skills, you can store the SMB password as a "domain credential" using `CredWrite()`, which is equivalent to checking the "Remember password" box in Windows.)

On Linux, it depends on the program.

- GNOME's Gvfs accepts the `user@host` syntax, but appears to completely ignore the password. (However, you can store it in GNOME Keyring beforehand.)
- `smbclient` uses the same UNC syntax as Windows; however, it has an `--authentication-file` option from which credentials could be read.
- Both programs above are using *libsmbclient*, and can use Kerberos authentication instead of passwords: run `kinit user@YOUR.DOMAIN` and use `smbclient -k //host/share`. This is more secure than password authentication.

Note that putting passwords into URIs is deprecated, and you should not rely on it being supported *anywhere*.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much! I actually already solved it with creating a API to share the info. But this is sure usefull information i would else never known!